# WPF drag and drop C# drag image as well

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

i dynamic populate a dock panel with answers from database and another dock panel with questions from the database as well. the answers will be populated as Labels and i trying to do a drag and drop with labels to textblock . Yes i can drag and drop , but the thing is i want to drag the label too . For example if the Label content is Hello , i want the hello to be dragged over with the word " hello " as well , for now , when i drag it , it doesn't drag the word as well , but when i drop it into a textbox , the word " hello " is dropped . I want to drag the animation or word as well together with the cursor .

this is my code :

```
        private void PopulateQuestion(int activityID, int taskID)
    {
        IList<Model.question> lstQuestion = qn.GetRecords(taskID, activityID);
        StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
        StackPanel stp = new StackPanel();
        foreach (Model.question qhm in lstQuestion)
        {

            StackPanel sp1 = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal }; // Question
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = qhm.QuestionContent;
            tb.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            tb.FontSize = 24;
            sp1.Children.Add(tb);

            StackPanel sp2 = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal }; // Answer
            Label tb1 = new Label();
            tb1.Content = qhm.Answer;
            tb1.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            tb1.FontSize = 24;
            tb1.MouseLeftButtonDown += tb1_Click;
            sp2.Children.Add(tb1);

            TextBox tbox = new TextBox();
            tbox.Width = 100;
            tbox.FontSize = 24;
            tbox.AllowDrop = true;
            tbox.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;

            if (qhm.Answer.Trim().Length > 0 )
            {

                sp1.Children.Add(tbox);

            }

            sp.Children.Add(sp1);
            stp.Children.Add(sp2);
        }

        dockQuestion.Children.Add(sp);
        dockAnswer.Children.Add(stp);
    }

    private void tb1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)sender;
        DataObject dataObj = new DataObject(lbl.Content);
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(lbl, dataObj, DragDropEffects.All);

        lbl.IsEnabled = false;
        lbl.Foreground = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#FFFB3B46"); // Red
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the strategy outlined in the link below, which essentially creates a new window and causes the window position to be updated with the mouse cursor.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2007/07/12/drag-drop-in-wpf-explained-end-to-end.aspx

So the main points from the page are that you decorate the cursor using the Adorner.

You can use the this.DragSource.GiveFeedback and other events on the DragSource event handlers to set up the Adorner.

Once you have the event handler, that gives you the opportunity to do something.

```
//Here we create our adorner.. 
_adorner = new DragAdorner(DragScope, (UIElement)this.dragElement, true, 0.5);
_layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(DragScope as Visual);
_layer.Add(_adorner);
```

So you can create your own Adorner by subclassing it.  You can find more info on creating a custom adorner here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx

Comment: hi there , thanks for the link but i can barely understand it  , new to this ....

Comment: thanks for your time . I am still confused but i suppose i'll just create a any event handler and do adorner in it ? or do i need to find position of the mouse cursor using mousedown events?

Comment: From the beginning part of the source it looks like mouse event handlers are added as the first step:this.DragSource.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown and this.DragSource.PreviewMouseMove

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adamroot/archive/2008/02/19/shell-style-drag-and-drop-in-net-wpf-and-winforms.aspx

the default wpf drag & drop's animation is ugly, if you want be show some text or image while dragging,you need
do something more.